# Using JSONP with the MongoDB Simple API

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, jsonp

I am trying to use MongoDB's simple API along with JSONP to perform queries from the clients locally on the server.  My Javascript function looks like this:

```
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:28017/test/firstImport/";

$.ajax({url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: false,
        jsonp: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: 'true',
        success: function(data){
        console.log("success")  ; 
        }});
```

I have also changed the url to:

```
url = "http://127.0.0.1:28017/test/firstImport?callback=?"
```

with the same results of a failed GET:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:28017/test/firstImport/?callback=jQuery172028897865186445415_1382730114314&_=1382730123431
```

I have have been researching this but have come up with nothing so far.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the error? Are you saying nothing works? Have you properly enabled the API?

Comment: Yes, I set rest = true and jsonp = true in the config file and restarted.
I am not getting anything back and the chrome developer console returns `GET http://127.0.0.1:28017/test/firstImport/?callback=jQuery172028897865186445415_1382730114314&_=1382730123431 `
with a red x next to it like it did not execute.

Comment: Also If I change my success parameter to `function(data){console.log(data)}`
It does not return any results.

Comment: If you're seeing `GET http://127.0.0.1:28017/test/firstImport/?callback=…` then your `$.ajax` parameters must be wrong because Mongo expects a "jsonp" parameter to provide the callback function. Looking at your options object though, I can't see where. I'm using the same code structure & it's working. What happens if you visit  `http://127.0.0.1:28017/test/firstImport/?jsonp=test` in a browser window?